# Spectral sequence of a filtered complex: convergence conditions and abelian categories

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories, spectral-sequences

There is a theorem that if given a filtered complex and the filtration is bounded then there is a spectral sequence whose 0th and 1st page have specific forms and the sequence converges to (co)homology of the complex.
I followed the proof in Serge Lang's book, Algebra and I asked myself two questions yet unanswered:

1. Does the filtration have to be bounded for the spectral seq. to converge?
2. The proof seems to take place in category of modules, not in a general abelian category. I tried to generalize the statement somehow using Freyd Mitchell embedding thm, but it wasn't easy. Does one have to be able to do 'diagram-chasing' in order to prove the theorem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the convergence issue, a possible reference is the chapter 3 of McCleary's *A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences*. For example you have the following theorem (I will explain the terms), for a cocomplex and an increasing filtration:

**Theorem**. Let $(A,d,F)$ be a filtered dg-module such that the filtration is exhaustive and weakly convergent. Then the associated spectral sequence with $E^{p,q}_1 = F^p H^{p+q}(A,d) / F^{p+1} H^{p+q}(A,d)$ converges to $H(A,d)$.

Here a filtration is said to be:

- exhaustive if $A = \bigcup_s F^s A$;
- weakly convergent if for all $p$, $$Z^p_\infty = \bigcap_r Z^p_r \iff F^p A \cap \operatorname{ker} d = \bigcap_r (F^p A \cap d^{-1} (F^{p+r} A)).$$

This is one possible example of a convergence theorem. In general you do need conditions on the filtration to ensure convergence; boundedness is just one that is simple to state. You can easily construct examples of spectral sequences that don't converge / converge to nonsense if you remove these conditions, for example if I set $F^p A = 0$ for all $p$ I will obviously not get anything interesting; if I set $F^p A = A$ for all $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ another kind of pathology occurs.

---

It is possible to work with spectral sequences in general abelian categories. One of the most important application is the [Grothendieck spectral sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_spectral_sequence) that generalizes many other examples (the Leray SS, the universal coefficient SSs, the Serre SS...). There are a few references given in McCleary's book in chapter 12 under the heading "Abelian categories". In particular he cites Gelfand and Manin's *Methods of homological algebras*; but I recommend that you familiarize yourself thoroughly with spectral sequences in modules before attacking general spectral sequences.